# inserción de datos por URL usando GET a una base de datos en Digital Ocean

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, get

Necesito enviar datos por URL a mi base de datos alojada en Digital Ocean, es un proyecto LARAVEL version 5.5, esta incersion la hago de forma independiente es decir tengo un archivo de conexion diferente al .env y tengo otro donde subo los datos a la base de datos, es este:

```
<?php
$password= "XXXX";

//Importamos la configuracion
require("config.php");
if ($_GET['pass'] == $password)
{
// Leemos los valores que nos llegan por GET 
$Potencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[Potencia]);
$Irms = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[Irms]);
$con_dia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[con_dia]);
$con_mes = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[con_mes]);
$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[user_id]);
$part_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[part_id]);
//fecha actual

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

$pru1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$pru2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$now = strtotime($pru1);
$now2 = strtotime($pru2);

// Esta es la instruccion para insertar los valores
//anterior  $query = "INSERT INTO consumes(Potencia, Irms, user_id, part_id)

$query = "INSERT INTO consumes(Potencia, Irms, user_id, part_id, created_at, up$

// Ejecutamos la instruccion
mysqli_query($con, $query);
mysqli_close($con);
echo "Página para subir los datos<br />";
echo "<br />Potencia = $Potencia <br />";
echo "<br />Irms = $Irms <br />";
echo "<br />con_dia = $con_dia <br />";
echo "<br />con_mes = $con_mes <br />";
echo "<br />User_id = $user_id <br />";
echo "<br />Part_id = $part_id <br />";
echo "<br />creado el  = $pru1 <br />";
echo "<br />Actualizado el  = $pru2 <br />";

}
else
{
echo "Acceso bloqueado. Necesitas la contraseña para acceder a la base de dato$
}
?>
```

El ingreso de datos lo efectuo por la URL de la siguiente forma:

http://IP_SEVIDOR/prueba.php? 
   pass=XXXX&Potencia=8&Irms=8&con_dia=0&con_mes=0&user_id=8&part_id=8

La pagina me muestra los datos en el navegador pero no realiza la inserción en la Base de datos, esto me indica que la conexion a esta es correcta.

Local me funciona, la version de PHP local es 7.1 y la del servidor es 7.2. Será este el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Fue un error de descuido, me faltaban dos campos en la query, no estaba incluyendo con_dia o con_mes en el INSERT.